# Joining Strings Together Randomly in Python

Tags: python, list, join, random, range

I'm looking for the words in the list to be joined together in different combinations, but it's only returning single word results. I'm looking for strings like 'whywho' 'whatwhywhen' 'howwhywhatwho' etc.

```
import random, sys
words = ['why', 'who', 'what', 'why', 'when', 'how']

for i in range(100):
    print ''.join(random.choice(words[:randint(1, 4)]))
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `random.choice`?

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456617/return-a-random-word-from-a-word-list-in-python

Comment: I would generate a random word from the list, put it into a second list, then append all of the indices in the second list.

Comment: To randomize the strings that are outputted... an attempt anyways

Comment: The [docs for `random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) says that it will return a single random element from a sequence. You should switch to Python version 3.6+ while you are still learning ... https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 8):

use `sample` function from random package.

```
import random
words = ['why', 'who', 'what', 'why', 'when', 'how']

for i in range(100):
    print ''.join(random.sample(words, random.randint(1,4)))
```

**EDIT**

If you don't care which element to be repeated,

```
for i in range(100):
    arr = random.sample(words, random.randint(1,4))
    # select a random element from arr and append to self     
    arr.append(random.choice(words))
    print ''.join(arr)
```

if you don't want this operation to be repeated if repetitions are already there,

```
    arr = random.sample(words, random.randint(1,4))
    # first check if array contains repetetive elements or not 
    # if contains, go and join the list, otherwise select a random element
    # from array and add to that array again  
    if not [el for el in arr if arr.count(l) > 1]:
        arr.append(random.choice(words))                
    print ''.join(arr)
```

you might also want to use `insert` method defined for lists, which simply inserts an element to desired index in list.

```
arr = random.sample(words, random.randint(1,4))
if not [el for el in arr if arr.count(el) > 1]:
    r = random.choice(arr)
    index_of_r = arr.index(r)
    arr.insert(index_of_r, r)
print ''.join(arr)
```

Check [this](https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/WingedAuthenticAmurminnow) for last one.

Comment: Is there a way to make this spit out results that repeat words from the list?

Comment: i didn't understand your last question. isn't that what you were asking for? selecting random sublists from given list and join them?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was badly phrased. Is there a chance that two words from the list would be repeated like 'whywhywhat'?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer!

`random.choice` returns **one** random element from the input sequence. What *you* are doing is that you are generating a slice of random size from the `words` list, from which you are choosing a single element.

The following does what you want:

```
''.join(random.choices(words, k=random.randint(1, 4)))
```

`random.choices` returns a `k` sized list of random elements from the input sequence. These elements are chosen *with replacement*, meaning that you may have more than one occurrence of an element from `words`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out. Just find a random index and `join` it with a random list. To count the number of times a word was produced use the `Counter` object from the `collections` namespace.

```
import random as rand
import sys
from collections import Counter
words = ['why', 'who', 'what', 'why', 'when', 'how']
list = []

for i in range(100):
    # print(words[rand.randint(1, 4)].join(words[:rand.randint(1, 4)]))
    # print(rand.sample(words, rand.randint(1, 4))) Prints out a 'list' of current combination
    list += rand.sample(words, rand.randint(1, 4))

c = Counter(list)

print(c) # Counter({'why': 93, 'who': 48, 'what': 46, 'how': 46, 'when': 35})
```

Comment: But if the randomly selected words are, for example, "who" and "why", then joining them will give you `'wwhohwhoy'`. `join` is not the same thing as concatenation.

Comment: @Kevin I thought so too at first, but that's not what this code does - it calls join on `words[:rand.randint(1, 4)]`, which is a list.

Comment: That said, it's certainly very hard to read. This would benefit from some variables to store intermediate results.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't see the colon.