# ANSI C: How to split a string by newline and get a random line

Tags: c, string, random, strtok

I'm a new to C and got stuck with subj. I can split string with `strtok` but I don't know how to get a random token.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by random token ?

Comment: You need to know the number of the tokens first. In a second run you may choose a random one.

Comment: @sambowry: you don't need to know the number of tokens first. If you want to retrieve a random line from a file, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016240. (The algorithm works for getting a random line from a string containing many lines too, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse it twice, then get a random number and pick one, which you collect on the second pass of the same string.

Or, you can do it in a single pass if you use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Mastering reservoir sampling will be a very useful way of learning C as a side to learning some maths! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following pseudocode shows how to return a candidate uniformly selected among the tokens of the string:

```
string result = null;
int tokens = 0;
while (true) {
  string candidate = next token;
  if (candidate does not exist) break;
  tokens = tokens + 1;
  if ((a random integer selected between 0 and tokens-1) == 0) result = token;
}
return result;
```

This is a special case of *Algorithm R* from section 3.4.2 of Volume II of Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*.

Comment: The proper name for this algorithm is reservoir sampling, specialised to selecting a single element, whereas reservoir sampling can of course be used for tracking a representative sample in a stream