# Randomly selecting lines from files

Tags: python, perl, shell

I have bunch of files and very file has a header of 5 lines. In the rest of the file, pair of line form an entry. I need to randomly select entry from these files. 
How can i select random files and random entry(pair of line, excluding header) ?

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: Does the header tell you the number of entries in the file? Are the entries fixed in size within a given file?

Comment: About 1000000 entries in each file.

Comment: Please post an example of what you're dealing with. And what you've tried so far.

Comment: See this question for selecting a random line from a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232237/whats-the-best-way-to-return-a-random-line-in-a-text-file-using-c

Comment: Header just tells the time stamp and what each row contains and things like that

Comment: @Ziad I was writing a python script that takes filenaes as input randomly selects a file and reads the file and randomly selects couple of lines with the random number+ header length

Comment: @AlgoMan: You still haven't answered one question. Are the entries fixed in size?

Comment: @Moron Usually the entries are per day entry, But there might be missing data, so size is not fixed

Comment: @Ether No its not a homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file is small enough, read the pairs of lines into memory and select randomly from that data structure. If the file is too large, Eugene Y provides the right answer: use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Here's an intuitive explanation for the algorithm.

```
Process the file line by line.
pick = line, with probability 1/N, where N = line number
```

In other words, on line 1, we will pick line 1 with `1/1` probability. On line 2, we will **change** the pick to line 2, with `1/2` probability. On line 3, we will change the pick to line 3, with `1/3` probability. Etc.

For an intuitive proof, imagine a file with 3 lines:

```
        1            Pick line 1.
       / \
     .5  .5
     /     \
    2       1        Switch to line 2?
   / \     / \
 .67 .33 .33 .67
 /     \ /     \
2       3       1    Switch to line 3?
```

The probability for each outcome:

```
Line 1: .5 * .67     = 1/3
Line 2: .5 * .67     = 1/3
Line 3: .5 * .33 * 2 = 1/3
```

From there, the rest is induction. For example, suppose the file has 4 lines. We've already convinced ourselves that as of line 3, every line so far (1, 2, 3) will have an equal chance of being our *current* selection. When we advance to line 4, it will have a `1/4` chance of being picked -- exactly what it should be, thus reducing the probabilities on the previous 3 lines by exactly the right amount (`1/3 * 3/4 = 1/4`).

Here's the [Perl FAQ answer](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-select-a-random-line-from-a-file?), adapted to your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Ignore 5 lines.
<> for 1 .. 5;

# Use reservoir sampling to select pairs from remaining lines.
my (@picks, $n);
until (eof){
    my @lines;
    $lines[$_] = <> for 0 .. 1;

    $n ++;
    @picks = @lines if rand($n) < 1;
}

print @picks;
```

Comment: Great explanation of the algorithm. Nit: I think the OP said that two lines make up an entry, so your program would need a minor modification to account for that (i.e. add another readline, divide no. of lines in the rand() call by two). Crazy idea: one might be able to use `File::Stream`, which let's you use a regexp in $/ to read two lines at once. Of course, that would be a bad idea in production because the module's extremely slow.

Answer (score 7):

You may find [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-select-a-random-line-from-a-file?) useful.

Comment: Its worth noting that its a single-pass algorithm which only keeps two lines in memory at any time.

Comment: I would have posted this as CW, since you're (presumably) not the author of this faq item.

Comment: +1 Clever algorithm. I learned something today. Nit: I guess nowadays, we should drop the preceding "srand".

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "1,5d" < FILENAME | sort -R | head -2
```

Comment: Interesting. but where is the "-R" switch (presumably for "Randomize" supported?  I just checked on Linux (RHEL5.4, coreutils 5.97...), Mac OS X (10.5.8), and FreeBSD (6.4).

Answer (score 3):

### Python solution - reads file only once and requires little memory

Invoke like so `getRandomItems(file('myHuge.log'), 5, 2)` - will return list of 2 lines

```
from random import randrange

def getRandomItems(f, skipFirst=0, numItems=1):
    for _ in xrange(skipFirst):
        f.next()
    n = 0; r = []
    while True:
        try:
            nxt = [f.next() for _ in range(numItems)]
        except StopIteration: break
        n += 1
        if not randrange(n):
            r = nxt
    return r
```

Returns empty list if it could not get the first passable items from f. The code's only requirement is that argument `f` is an iterator (supports `next()` method). Hence we can pass something different than file, say we want to see the distribution:

```
>>> s={}
>>> for i in xrange(5000):
...     r = getRandomItems(iter(xrange(50)))[0]
...     s[r] = 1 + s.get(r,0)
... 
>>> for i in s: 
...     print i, '*' * s[i]
... 
0 ***********************************************************************************************
1 **************************************************************************************************************
2 ******************************************************************************************************
3 ***************************************************************************
4 *************************************************************************************************************************
5 ********************************************************************************
6 **********************************************************************************************
7 ***************************************************************************************
8 ********************************************************************************************
9 ********************************************************************************************
10 ***********************************************************************************************
11 ************************************************************************************************
12 *******************************************************************************************************************
13 *************************************************************************************************************
14 ***************************************************************************************************************
15 *****************************************************************************************************
16 ********************************************************************************************************
17 ****************************************************************************************************
18 ************************************************************************************************
19 **********************************************************************************
20 ******************************************************************************************
21 ********************************************************************************************************
22 ******************************************************************************************************
23 **********************************************************************************************************
24 *******************************************************************************************************
25 ******************************************************************************************
26 ***************************************************************************************************************
27 ***********************************************************************************************************
28 *****************************************************************************************************
29 ****************************************************************************************************************
30 ********************************************************************************************************
31 ********************************************************************************************
32 ****************************************************************************************************
33 **********************************************************************************************
34 ****************************************************************************************************
35 **************************************************************************************************
36 *********************************************************************************************
37 ***************************************************************************************
38 *******************************************************************************************************
39 **********************************************************************************************************
40 ******************************************************************************************************
41 ********************************************************************************************************
42 ************************************************************************************
43 ****************************************************************************************************************************
44 ****************************************************************************************************************************
45 ***********************************************************************************************
46 *****************************************************************************************************
47 ***************************************************************************************
48 ***********************************************************************************************************
49 ****************************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in Python.  Assuming you can read a whole file into memory.

```
#using python 2.6
import sys
import os
import itertools
import random

def main(directory, num_files=5, num_entries=5):
    file_paths = os.listdir(directory)

    # get a random sampling of the available paths
    chosen_paths = random.sample(file_paths, num_files)

    for path in chosen_paths:
        chosen_entries = get_random_entries(path, num_entries)
        for entry in chosen_entries:
            # do something with your chosen entries
            print entry

def get_random_entries(file_path, num_entries):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        # read the lines and slice off the headers
        lines = file.readlines()[5:]

        # group the lines into pairs (i.e. entries)
        entries = list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(lines)]*2))

        # return a random sampling of entries
        return random.sample(entries, num_entries)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #use optparse here to do fancy things with the command line args
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Links: [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), [random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample), [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

Comment: My python version on the server where the log is . 2.4.3

Comment: @EnTerr It's exactly as many lines as your answer if you take out the whitespace and comments; both of which are lacking in yours.

Comment: ugh, loading all lines in memory is silly - say there a million lines in file of 50MB?

Comment: @EnTerr, I wouldn't worry about 50MB or a million lines.  The problems might begin when we get up near 500MB - 1GB. because at any given point there could be up to two copies of the files content in memory (plus a little overhead from the other variables).

Answer (score 0):

Another Python option; reading the contents of all files into memory:

```
import random
import fileinput

def openhook(filename, mode):
    f = open(filename, mode)
    headers = [f.readline() for _ in range(5)]
    return f

num_entries = 3
lines = list(fileinput.input(openhook=openhook))
print random.sample(lines, num_entries)
```

Comment: My python version on the server where the log is . 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Two other means to do so:
1- by generators (may still require a lot of memory):
http://www.usrsb.in/Picking-Random-Items--Take-Two--Hacking-Python-s-Generators-.html

2- by a clever seeking (best method actually):
http://www.regexprn.com/2008/11/read-random-line-in-large-file-in.html

I here copy the code of the clever Jonathan Kupferman:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,random

filename="averylargefile"
file = open(filename,'r')

#Get the total file size
file_size = os.stat(filename)[6]

while 1:
      #Seek to a place in the file which is a random distance away
      #Mod by file size so that it wraps around to the beginning
      file.seek((file.tell()+random.randint(0,file_size-1))%file_size)

      #dont use the first readline since it may fall in the middle of a line
      file.readline()
      #this will return the next (complete) line from the file
      line = file.readline()

      #here is your random line in the file
      print line
```