# Choosing a random file from a directory (with a large number of files) in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a directory with a large number of files (~1mil). I need to choose a random file from this directory. Since there are so many files, `os.listdir` naturally takes an eternity to finish.

Is there a way I can circumvent this problem? Maybe somehow get to know the number of files in the directory (without listing it) and choose the 'n'th file where n is randomly generated?

The files in the directory are randomly named.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: 2.6.30.10.1.amd64-smp #1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you control the names of the files in the directory?

Comment: Pure curiosity: how did you end up with ~1mil symbolic links in a directory, and why do you need a random one?

Comment: maybe maintain a file in that directory containing a list of all filenames

Comment: What is the purpose of having random symbolic links?  It seems you are searching for a solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: is it ok to rename the files? how random are the names?

Comment: I cannot rename the files; otherwise I could've numbered them in some way and chosen a random number in the program to select a random file...

Comment: yeah, so the only other way (far from being elegant) i could think of is creating another ~1mil numbered files to act as links to the original files. good luck.
(you would need a file contaning the total number of files also)

Answer (score 3):

Alas, I don't think there is a solution to your problem. One, I don't know of portable API that will return you the number of entries in directory (w/o enumerating them first). Two, I don't think there is API to return you directory entry by number and not by name.

So overall, a program will have to enumerate O(n) directory entries to get a single random one. The trivial approach of determining number of entries and then picking one will either require enough RAM to hold the full listing (`os.listdir()`) or will have to enumerate 2nd time the directory to find the random(n) item - overall `n+n/2` operations on average.

There is slightly better approach - but only slightly - see [randomly-selecting-lines-from-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009832#3011085). In short there is a way to pick random item from list/iterator with unknown length, while reading one item at a time and ensure that any item may be picked with equal probability. But this won't help with `os.listdir()` because it already returns `list` in memory that already contains all 1M+ entries - so you can as well ask it about `len()` ...

Comment: This is a good idea, I'm tempted to try this using the `os.listdir` generator function that Wayne suggested.

Comment: @NoneType: If you'd like to toy with it, sure. But I don't think an improvement of only 2x is worth the effort; you should be shooting for something linear or logarithmic. For that though you should be able to change the problem somehow... why exactly do you need to do this random selection of file, what's the need behind it? Do you have better knowledge of the file naming schema?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is even possible. Even at the VFS or filesystem level, there is no guarantee that a directory entry count is even maintained. For instance many filesystems simply record the combined byte size of the directory entry structures contained in a given directory.

Estimation may be made if directory entries are fixed size structures, but this is uncommon now (consider LFN for FAT32). Even if a given filesystem did provide an entry count without needing to iterate through a directory, or if the VFS cached a record of a directories length, these would definitely be operating system, filesystem, and kernel specific.

Comment: Would it help if all the files in the directory are symbolic links? On my system, all these links are 512B in size. So could we possibly extract the number of files using this and the combined directory size information?

Comment: I'm very hopeful that I'm wrong, I'm keen to see a nice technical answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need to the OP.

I think I will adopt a method of precaching: you store in a .txt file the list of all the files, then you can just do a clever seeking of a random line in your listing (without even having to load it in memory), and you're done!

Of course, you still have to update the cache, and more importantly define **when** you need to update the cache, but depending on your needs, it may be easy (just after a specific action, or when something changed, etc..).

A code to cleverly read a random line from a file, in Python, by Jonathan Kupferman:

http://www.regexprn.com/2008/11/read-random-line-in-large-file-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get this running:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-July/1213182.html

And that's probably the best possible solution to your problem, but only where `n` is small - if `n` goes large then os.listdir is probably just as good for your purpose.

I've hunted around and failed to find any other way to open a file in a directory. If I had more time I'd be inclined to play around a bit and generate my own ~1mil files.

---

I just thought of another way to do this: 
Assuming the files are constant - you're not getting any more or less - you could keep a list of the filenames in a sqlite database. Then it would be relatively simple to query the database for a name by a random `ROWID`. I don't know if you'll still be plagued by the long time to search for the correct file, but at least getting a filename should take a short amount.

Of course if the files in the directory are randomly named, you can rename the files(?) and put them into a directory structure like AdamK suggests.

Comment: I shall try the `listdir` generator function along with the random sampling heuristic that Nas Banov suggested. (i.e., uniform sampling across all file names while reading them one by one)

Answer (score 0):

try this, (here is very fast with 50K files...)

```
import glob
import random

list = glob.glob("*/*.*")
print list[random.randrange(0,list.__len__())]
```

Comment: This takes and equally large amount of time.

Comment: pls note `random.randrange(0,list.__len__())` is better written as `random.randrange(len(list))`