# How to put random lines from a file into a string in python?

Tags: python

what i want to do is write a code that has a file (in the code, no need to be input by user), and the code picks a random line from the file - whatever it is, a long line, an ip or even a word and at the end of the loop puts it into a string so i could use that in other parts of the code.

i tried using `randomchoice(lines)` but wasn't sure how to continue from here.
after that i tried using:

```
import random
def random_line(afile):
    line = next(afile)
    for num, aline in enumerate(afile):
      if random.randrange(num + 2): continue
      line = aline
    return line
```

which also for some reason didnt work for me.

Comment: When you say the code you've shown didn't work, what do you mean? Does it raise an exception? Return garbage? Always return the same thing?

Comment: afile is filename or filehandle ?

Comment: well if i understand this correctly `line` is the string that should get the random line value, and it doesn't for some reason. not sure what im doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last method you posted worked for me. Maybe you are not opening the file correctly. Here is another approach, using `random.choice`

```
import random

def random_line(f):
    return random.choice([line for line in f])

f = open("sample.txt", 'r')

print random_line(f)
```

**Edit:**

Another way would be (thanks to @zhangxaochen):

```
def random_line(f):
    return random.choice(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Short, but expensive if the file is big. It all gets read into memory at once.

Comment: @senshin +1, should be `afile`, not `f`

Comment: ok so proabably im not opening the file correctly. why did you open the file AFTER the random line?

Comment: `def random_line(f)` is just the declaration of the method, there is no problem. Note that I'm opening the file **before** calling `random_line(f)` in the print statement.

Comment: ALRIGHT! now that it works im not sure what i did wrong but that was very simple, thanks everyone!

Comment: Is it even necessary to use `f.readlines()` vs. `f`? I believe a file is naturally a sequence of lines all by itself.

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes, but `random.choice` requires something which can be indexed and which you can call `len` on.  (Again, in Python 2 -- can't check 3 right now.)

Comment: @DSM, I tested it on `xrange` believing it returned a generator, but when I test it on an actual generator function it fails for the exact reason you state. I stand corrected. That means my answer has an advantage over this one.

Answer (score 1):

Translating [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232248/5987) from C:

```
def random_line(afile):
    count = 0
    kept_line = None
    for line in afile:
        if random.randint(0, count) == 0:
            kept_line = line
        count += 1
    return kept_line
```

Edit: This appears to do the same thing as `random.choice`. I wonder if they use the same algorithm?

Edit 2: from the comments and a little experimentation it appears `random.choice` uses a different algorithm, which will be *much* more efficient if all of the elements are already in memory. This isn't usually the case for files unless you use `readlines`. There will be a tradeoff between having to keep the entire file in memory vs. having to calculate `n` random numbers.

Comment: `random.choice` is simply `seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]`.  (Python 2, anyway.)

Comment: @DSM a sequence can't be indexed directly. You have to take it one element at a time. Try `random.choice(xrange(1000))` for example.

Comment: which is why your algorithm isn't the same as `random.choice`.  (Although I wouldn't use the word `sequence` there, because a list is a sequence, and obviously can be directly indexed.)

Comment: @DSM I just reached the same conclusion which I left in a comment to the other answer.